# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with com.spring.model.Instruction

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public List<Instruction> listPAyment() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<Instruction> personsList = (List<Instruction>)session.createSQLQuery(
        "SELECT INSTRUCTIONKEY, BASECURRENCY,STATUSPROC, WHENMODIFIED FROM MyDB.INSTRUCTION"
    ).list();
    EXCEPTION HERE--->    for(Instruction p : personsList){
        System.out.println( "Payment::"+ p.toString()); 
    }
    return personsList;
}
```

I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with com.spring.model.Instruction` exception at above mentioned point, I am unable to find out what's wrong with casting in below code.
I have added `toString()` correctly in model class `Instruction`

Please assist

[2016/09/05 15:05:01:991 GMT+02:00] 00000040 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [/WEB-INF/views/instruction.jsp] in application [SpringMVCHibernate_war]. Exception created : [java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "instructionKey"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:59)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:460)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:510)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:55)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:174)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:778)
    at com.ibm._jsp._instruction._jspx_meth_c_forEach_0(_instruction.java:131)
    at com.ibm._jsp._instruction._jspx_meth_c_if_0(_instruction.java:179)
    at com.ibm._jsp._instruction._jspService(_instruction.java:95)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)

Jsp to iterate object:

```
      <c:forEach items="${listPersons}" var="instruction">
            <tr>
                <td>${instruction.instructionKey}</td>
                <td>${instruction.statusProc}</td>
                <td>${instruction.baseCurrency}</td> 
                <td>${instruction.whenModified}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

where   model.addAttribute("instruction", new Instruction());
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());

defined in controller.

Comment: Since you are explicitly asking for the columns from the table, the result will be an `Object[]` not `Instruction`

Comment: Thanks @Prashanth,tried that but getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "instructionKey" this exception

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @prasanth, I have updated question, please have a look.

Comment: I am not sure how to iterate returned Object[] in jsp

Answer (score 0):

You could pull from the DB into a class named :whatever: and give that class the variables that will be pulled from the DB and give it a toString method that you can call? Maybe?